# Getting data that is difficult connected with the input data, SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Firstly**, want to ask you (so my question would be more clear for you) if there an online database diagram tool (?) in which I can input my sql code and it will draw diagramm (with tables and their relationships) for me.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918620/are-there-any-online-database-schema-drawing-tools) and tried some tools, but most of them can only create tables and relationships between them, but not allow to import my sql.

**(2)** 
I need to get all classes connected with Teacher.
There are two types of connection: teacher may be the form-master or teacher may taugh this class.
How to get all classes which are connected to teacher.

**(3)** 1 more additional question: Am I right with constraints?

SQL Scheme ([scheme on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39971)):

```
CREATE TABLE `Subject` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Teacher` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `midname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `birthdate` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Class` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `digit` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `char` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `teacher_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_Class_Teacher` (`teacher_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Class_Teacher` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `ClassVsSubject` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `class_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `subject_id_class_id` (`subject_id`, `class_id`),
    INDEX `FK_ClassVsSubject_Class` (`class_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ClassVsSubject_Class` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ClassVsSubject_Subject` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `TeacherVsSubject` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `teacher_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `subject_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_TeacherVsSubject_Teacher` (`teacher_id`),
    INDEX `FK_TeacherVsSubject_Subject` (`subject_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_TeacherVsSubject_Teacher` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_TeacherVsSubject_Subject` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`id`)
);
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147439/sql-proc-diagram-generating-software-of-a-programm-flow) describes a tool I've used before, Code Visual To Flowchart, which takes say a SQL sproc and generates an ugly but usable visual diagram of the flow, at least.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for but I believe [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) does some of this.

Comment: @NicholasV., forget to say, that tool have to be 'online'

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, use something like:

```
select *
  from Class
 where teacher_id = 1

union

select Class.*
  from Class
       join ClassVsSubject on Class.id = ClassVsSubject.class_id
       join TeacherVsSubject on ClassVsSubject.subject_id = TeacherVsSubject.subject_id
 where TeacherVsSubject.teacher_id = 1
```

As you did not state which teacher is the starting point, I used that with id 1.

Please note that `union` gets rid of duplicate entries, there is no need to treat this separately.

For your data model (question 3), I think one gotcha is that you need different entries in the `subject` table for different classes and the same subject like 'Maths' or 'English', otherwise, the joins will not work:
Let's say subject "English" has id 1. Now, if the class with id 1 and the class with id 2 both have this subject, you would have the following data in ClassVsSubject:

```
class_id   subject_id
       1            1
       2            1
```

How do you want to enter into table TeacherVsSubject that the teacher with id 5 teaches English in class 1, but not in class 2? You cannot! If you enter a record with subject_id 1 and teacher_id 5, this would apply to all classes.

To remedy that, you could make one table from the two `ClassVsSubject` and `TeacherVsSubject`. This would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `class_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `teacher_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `subject_id_class_id` (`subject_id`, `class_id`, `teacher_id`),
    INDEX `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Class` (`class_id`),
    INDEX `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Teacher` (`teacher_id`),
    INDEX `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Subject` (`subject_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Class` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Teacher` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher_Subject` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`id`)
);
```

For the data model, you would not need the `id` column here, the primary key could be a combined key across all three foreign keys. But - depending on client software - it may be useful to have it. E. g. some OR mapping tools require a single column primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, going to try it a bit later. Gotcha? :) Google Translator don't know what is it! Can you explain? Odd? One point? One moment? If I make one table `ClassVsSubjectVsTeacher`, I would have to add both teacher and subject all time when I try to add subject for class. Now I add subject, add teacher which will taught subject and after that just choose some subjects for each class, so I don't need to put in each row what teacher will taught subject (like in one big table)

Comment: For gotcha, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming). According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha, this is a relaxed pronunciations of "I['ve] got you". I edited my answer to explain the problem with the table design more detailed.

Comment: Ghm. Thank you for your answer. I think you don't underrstand me a bit (sure you don't, because don't have describe of my system etc). I don't know in other countries, but in mine there are form-masters in classes (mom or dad of class:D he organize class). In `Class` field `teacher_id` show this type of connection. Another type is so: classes are learning subjects. Subjects are taught by teachers. I firstly add subject, after that choose teachers for it (possibly many) and after that choose which subjects class will learn. This is 2nd type.

Comment: So I don't choose teacher for class and then subject. I just choose subject which teacher is connected with.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Ok, if two teachers are connected with a subject, this means they bot have lessons in each class that is connected with the subject?

Comment: @FrankPI it is possible. It is not main which teacher will teach student Bob1 or Bob2. Main is that student will learn math (we don't care bob1 or bob2). You suggest to specify teacher?

Comment: Just as your question 2 asks for teachers who "may taugh this class", I was assuming it is important which teacher teaches which subject in which class. If this is not important, then you can leave your data model as it is. But then my solution would deliver all classes that get a subject taught which the teacher teaches, no matter if this teacher really teaches this subject in this class or only in another class. And nobody is able to give you the (in my opinion) correct answer of only those classes where the teacher really teaches a subject, as the data model does not allow to code this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `select * from Class where teacher_id = some_id_from_Teacher_table`

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this wouldn't help. It will return only classes where teacher with `teacher_id` is form-master.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav This is a valid answer to: "How to get all classes which are connected to teacher." It may not have been as robust as you want. You should put a sample output of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Shawn, I don't think that it is valid just because it shows wrong connection. I said: `I need to get all classes connected with Teacher. There are two types of connection: teacher may be the form-master or teacher may taugh this class. How to get all classes which are connected to teacher.` Not only 1 type connection. Both types conectin needed.